# Is this a valid definition of "self-similar fractal"?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, definition, fractals

I have always been fascinated by self-similarity, particularly in fractals. I was always wanted to find a simple definition of a self-similar fractal. Of course, saying "is self-similar, and is a fractal (has noninteger fractal dimension)" is a valid definition, but not the one I was looking for.

So here I go. A shape $S$ in euclidean space is a self-similar fractal if:

- It is self similar (this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity#Definition) seems as suitable as any, but feel free to use another if you prefer).
- It **does not** tessellate the plane (if it does, it is *trivially* self-similar).

For example, the square is self-similar (if you remove the right and bottom edge), but it also tessellates the plane. A line segment too is self similar, and, using an uncountable number of lines it can tessellate the plane. An octagon can not tessellate the plane, but it is not self-similar. So these things are not fractals.

[Sierpinski's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) is self-similar but can not tessellate the plane. The [Koch Curve](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Koch_curve) is also self-similar and can not tessellate the plane (if you try the same trick with the line, it will necessarily intersect itself).

---

My question is, is the above definition equivalent to being a fractal and being strictly self-similar in the plane? Does it work in other euclidean dimensions? How about other unbounded metric spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of self-similarity is solid - essentially, a set $E$ is self-similar if it is the invariant set of an IFS $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^m$:
$$E = \bigcup_{i=1}^m f_i(E).$$
For example, the unit square is self-similar since it is the invariant set of the list of four similarities $f_i(x) = x/2 + s_i$, where each $s_i$ is a shift vector:
$$
\begin{align}
  s_0 &= \langle 0,0 \rangle \\
  s_1 &= \langle 1/2,0 \rangle \\  
  s_2 &= \langle 0,1/2 \rangle \\
  s_3 &= \langle 1/2,1/2 \rangle.
\end{align}
$$
Your insistence that the set not tile the plane is more difficult, however. I'd say that the square fits well into the realm of fractal geometry, as it's self-similar. Now, suppose we change the vector $s_3$ above to 
$$s_3 = \langle -1/2,-1/2 \rangle.$$
Then, we get the following set:

[image]

Is this a fractal set? As it's a subset of a plane that contains a solid disk, its dimension is 2. Its boundary has dimension $\log(3)/\log(2)$, however. And, believe it or not, it does tile the plane. If we shift it two units to the left or to the right or up or down or $2\sqrt{2}$ units diagonally Northeast or Southwest, the filled parts match perfectly with the holes:

[image]

How about the [twindragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve#Twindragon)?

[image]

Solid proofs that these sets tile the plane is tricky. They both fall under a general scheme elaborated by Christoff Bandt in the *Proceedings of the AMS* in 1991. I published my own small contribution in The Mathematica Journal a few years ago. My paper was based on Bandt's work as well as work by Bob Strichartz and Yang Wang.

- [Self-similar sets 5: Integer matrices and fractal Tilings of $\mathbb R^n$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2048752)
- [Generating self-affine tiles and their boundaries](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v11i1/SelfAffineTiles.html)
- [Geometry of self-affine tiles I](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/ywang/Reprints/boundaryI.pdf)

That second paper describes how I generated the images here. Also, the boundary of the twindragon is discussed in [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194788/on-the-boundary-of-the-twindragon/195243#195243).

Comment: The twin dragon is cool.

Comment: Wait, according to Wikipedia the fractal dimension of the twin dragons is 2! How bizarre.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about how the first example tiles the plane?

Comment: aren't fractals : self-similar + the homeomorphisms are contrative around some points ?

Comment: @MarkMcClure although it would be infinite area, I don't see how it tiles the plane.

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, it is tricky. I hope that the edit helps.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes. Even stronger - the maps must be strict similarity transformations. Note that the maps here are, in fact strict similarity contractions and, therefore, must have unique fixed points, though they might be a little tricky to see.

Comment: I'm lost now. I can't see if it is the space which is fractal or some function on some space, and for what norm/metric (or topology) we define it is contractive, and contractive around what point (to ensure the recursion of self-similarity) : I can't find an intuitive definition of "fractal" with this vocabulary.

Comment: @user1952009 I didn't meant to confuse you! My own feeling is that "fractal geometry" is a *subject* and is as loosely defined as, say, "linear algebra". We know what we are studying when we do linear algebra - linear transformations, matrices, and many related topics. Similarly, we know what we are studying when we do fractal geometry: Iterated function systems, Hausdorff measure, and many related topics. I think the reason people haven't been able to define "fractal" is because the topics in fractal geometry are equally applicable to simple and complicated sets.

Comment: ... Note also that the question at hand refers specifically to "*self-similar* fractal*, which I took to mean "self-similar set". Now that is a specific concept and my answer essentially says that "invariant set of an IFS* is exactly correct while "doesn't tile the plane" isn't really relevant.

Comment: @MarkMcClure it does, thanks

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes.